# Downloading data from google finance using selenium (Python)

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, web, screen-scraping

I am trying to download stock data from Google Finance using the selenium module. Is there a way to use Google Chrome for this, or do I have to use Firefox by calling `browser = webdriver.Firefox()` ?

Secondly, if I have to use firefox is there a way to default the browser to download rather than ask for permission everytime? I have tried to do this by opening a Firefox browser and changing the options, but it doesn't seem to stick when I run my script.

Thanks in advance for the input.

Comment: When you say downloading data do you mean download any kind of file?

Comment: of course you can use chrome, `dr = webdriver.Chrome("executable_path")`, what are you trying to download?

Comment: I'm trying to download a CSV file. I tried the piece of code you suggested and I got a traceback error. It says, "'executable_path' executable needs to be available in the path." Any ideas? I'm trying to download two stock's data and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to use Google Chrome for this

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
```

> Secondly, if I have to use firefox is there a way to default the browser to download rather than ask for permission everytime?

if its ask for some permission -- this is because of your windows configuration. Its not related to selenium.